# GAE backend service insert doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, backend

my entity class is

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    @Persistent
    private String userName;

    @Persistent
    private String password;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;

        this.password = password;

    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;

    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;

    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;

    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;

    }

    public Key getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

i generated a endpoint class, and then deployed it to GAE.

I went to the api explorer

```
https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://ig-project-1280.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/userendpoint/v1/userendpoint.insertUser?_h=4&resource=%257B%250A++%2522password%2522%253A+%2522welcome1%2522%252C%250A++%2522userName%2522%253A+%2522vik.ceo%2540gmail.com%2522%250A%257D&

and did the insert operation. The error come up is:
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
    at photography.viks.app.ig.entity.UserEndpoint.containsUser(UserEndpoint.java:152)
    at photography.viks.app.ig.entity.UserEndpoint.insertUser(UserEndpoint.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NullPointerException` when the method `UserEndpoint.containsUser(UserEndpoint.java:152)` is invoked. 
Your Exception is wrapped in backend service exception class provided by the google api endpoint layer on your application. 
Just check your code on that class and you'll find the problem.